# How to load more(Eg: 50) jpg images to animating quickly by using NSTimer?(Ipad)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiimageview

this is my NSTimer code

```
   myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.1 target: self
                                             selector: @selector(callRightRotation:) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];

-(void) callRightRotation:(NSTimer*)myTimer 
  {
       ImageView.tag =[ImageView tag]+1;

           if ([ImageView tag]==50) 
                ImageView.tag=1;

     [ImageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"kisok01%i.png",[ImageView tag]]]];

      if ([ImageView tag]==1 || [ImageView tag]==50 )
       {
             [myTimer invalidate];
              myTimer= nil;


        }

   }
```

Here loading images in **ipad** is perfectly working, but very hardly  ......here i am using **".jpg"** formate images, one image minimum 300kb ...

### Here my questions is

```
     1. Is it possible loading very fast and smoothly ?
     2. if its not possible is there any alternative solution?
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use ASIHTTPRequest instead of timmer for this, so your image will get load smoothly in background. and you can work with other controls of same view.

## import "ASIHTTPRequest.h"

//In a method

[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(DownLoadImageInBackground:) withObject:imgUrlArr];

-(void) DownLoadImageInBackground:(NSArray *)imgUrlArr1

{

```
NSURL * url = [Image URL];

ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

}

-(void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request

{

```
NSLog(@"URL Fail : %@",request.url);

NSError *error = [request error];

   // you can give here alert too..
```

}

-(void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request

{

```
NSData *responseData = [request responseData];
UIImage *imgInBackground = [[UIImage alloc]
                     initWithData:responseData];
[imageView setImage: imgInBackground];
```

}

Comment: thanks for u r replay !!! but my problem is i want like below code usin nstimer http://gggadgets.com/2009/09/25/tutorial-how-to-run-iphone-apps-on-a-mac/